# For R Lavaan users: how do you overcome variables that are not normal?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am working on my dissertation and need to fit a path model, however, from using the MVN package in R, I found that all my variables are not multivariate normal.

Therefore,

1. does the lavaan package offer an argument to fit non-normal variables?
2. what non-parametric methods are there for such non-normal variables?
   heard from a friend that I have to use *asymptotic distribution* for this. I found that an argument in lavaan does this: NACOV, but i am not sure how to use it.

Thank you.

Comment: A few discussions of this you might find relevant: (1) From Research Gate: Chien, Chin-Lung. (2016). Re: Multivariate normal assumption and path analysis. Retrieved from: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Multivariate_normal_assumption_and_path_analysis/5797612ced99e126a93691da/citation/download. (2) From the sister site Cross Validated (the statistics stack exchange): https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/351593/184400 (particularly relevant), https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/221053/184400

Comment: thanks, will look into these